# How can I achieve a text area, or something similar, that consist of many line of texts as individual item?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, frontend

Basically is something like this in the image. Each line of text is an item.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML has you covered with the `HTMLSelectElement` along with the `multiple` attribute:

```css
select[multiple] {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  <option value="foobar">FooBar</option>
  <option value="john">John</option>
  <option value="jill">Jill</option>
</select>
```